# How to handle dynamic amount of rows and columns in CSS3 grids?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid

In css3, I have data that needs to be in a css3 grid, but the problem is that it is dynamic amount of rows and columns based on the data.

I seen the code examples, but not sure how to write the css to support this.

Here is some examples:

The first column is always there, then based on a value (from the json ajax), there is 2 extra columns (eg. value being 5 means 1 + 2*5 = 11 columns). I am aware of repeat function in css3 grid, but then I would have to set that with javascript as it requires putting in the value in the code.

Then, for rows, I could have a dynamic amount of rows. I don't want to set a row number explicitly for each cell in each row because then again I would need to set it with javascript. Is there something I can use to say for certain cells, it should start in a new row?

Thanks

Comment: Read about *explicit* and *implicit* rows/columns in CSS Grid. Explicit tracks are the ones you define. Implicit tracks are the ones the grid creates automatically to handle a variety of different scenarios.

Comment: i did read them, but they imply you set the same value to all implicit ones which won't work in my case.

Comment: Maybe you can post a demo that illustrates what you're saying.